# IIS recycles the application pool when a cshtml file is checked out in TFS with Visual Studio 2010 with the solution open

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7, tfs

Here's my setup.

- MVC3 web application.
- TFS as source control.
- Visual Studio 2010 IDE.
- IIS 7

The application pool for my site recycles when I have the solution open in Visual Studio and I check out a cshtml file in TFS.  I have enabled logging in IIS and it reports that the recycle is caused by a config change.  This happens consistently, every time I check out or undo pending changes to a file when the solution is opened.  This occurs before I save the file or even make changes to it.

When the solution is not open in VS and I check out a cshtml file the application pool is not recycled.  Also, if I check out the cshtml file through the TFS context menu in windows explorer the application pool is not recycled.

I would like to know why a TFS checkout of a cshtml file when the solution is opened is causing the application pool to recycle.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you really want to know why? To me, this is something that only happens on a developer machine, and will not ever affect a production environment. So whatever happens is acceptable and should not be considered an issue at all.

Comment: You are correct in that this isn't a production issue, but I still want to know why this is happening.  Why would you NOT want to know how your system is running?